# How to fetch Creative URL for tiktok ad using /v1.3/report/integrated/get/ tiktok reporting api for basic type report

Tags: reporting, tiktok-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK9ut.jpg)

I am trying o fetch above creative using following URL and parameters

'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/report/integrated/get/?start_date=2023-05-01&end_date=2023-05-03&page_size=1000&page=1&report_type=BASIC&advertiser_id=7029336311521607681&metrics=["creative_name", "adgroup_id", "campaign_id", "adgroup_name","ad_name", "campaign_name", "spend", "impressions" ,"clicks", "complete_payment", "total_complete_payment_rate","web_event_add_to_cart", "placement_type", "vta_registration","total_registration", "form", "initiate_checkout", "opt_status"]&dimensions=["ad_id","stat_time_day"]&data_level=AUCTION_AD'

As per image attached creative column is in dimension but I am not able to find 'creative' field in api documentation for reporting api. I need to fetch creative URL or creative name for ads in the response.

I have gone through API documentation for tiktok reporting api 'https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1738864778664961'. I am trying to fetch BASIC report type where I am expecting creative column in dimension. But I am not able to fetch it.I have also tried other api like '/v1.3/ad/get/' to fetch creative for all the ads for an advertiser but there is no luck.